# What is the probability of guessing an IP correctly?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of someone guessing an IP correctly?

an IP is 4 blocks

Each block's maximum number is 255

Comment: $$\frac1{(255+1)^4}$$ without further knowledge. Agreed

Comment: @labbhattacharjee And with some more knowledge like addresses like 127.* and 224.* and above?

Answer (score 3):

If i understand the question correctly as the 4 sets are independent

$(1/256)*(1/256)*(1/256)*(1/256)$

Answer (score 3):

[image: xkcd comic]

If [this xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/195/) is accurate and still up-to-date, we can get it down to $$\frac{1}{(256-72)}\frac{1}{256}\frac{1}{256}\frac{1}{256}\approx\frac{1}{3 \times 10^9},$$ since $72$ blocks are unallocated.  In some cases, we can further eliminate some candidates, e.g. `192.168.?.?` provided the user is on another network ([ref.](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/g/192_168_0_0_def.htm)).

(See also [xkcd explained](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php?title=195) for this comic.)